# Method Order in generated class file by javac

Tags: java, javac

With JDK7, the reflection API has changed and now the methods returned by getDeclaredMethods() are **not** returned in the order in which they are declared in the source file.

Now my question is, does the .class file generated by javac contains methods *in the same order* in which they were defined in the source file OR it can write methods in random order too?

Comment: you can easily check yourself by compiling and looking at de-compiled code again (using decompiler)

Comment: @vishal_aim - Yup I have done that and for me its coming the same. I was more interested in knowing if it will happen across different jdk implementations/platforms.

Comment: From a pure language specification perspective, the order in which methods are declared does not have any effect on a program, so I don't see how a compiler that changes the order of the methods would be non compliant since the program would work exactly the same way...

Comment: @assylias: The problem is I have a legacy codebase which contains thousands of junits and some of them are dependent on the order in which they get executed. They used to work with JDK6(as the methods returned by reflection were in same order as defined), but failing intermittently  with jdk7.

Comment: @Manish: to be fair, JUnit **always** documented that your tests should not depend on each other and even more importantly: should not depend on the order in which they are run. (For example, here's  [a comment by Kent Beck himself on the topic](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/issues/174)).

Comment: @JoachimSauer: You are absolutely correct. I agree they are badly coded and the long term solution will be to correct the test cases, but I am looking for a quicker solution just to make them work as of now.

Comment: It sounds like some crazy things could help, such as making a script to add a custom annotation to your test cases.  The annotation would define the explicit order of execution.  Then extend JUnit to recognize the annotations and sort the test cases in your order.  But it might still be cheaper to fix the test cases.

Comment: @full.stack.ex: The approach has a drawback - modifying thousands of test cases and adding annotation to them. I am trying to keep the changes to a minimum and solution to be generic. If there is no other way, I will have to follow this path.

Comment: @Manish: The modification of test cases is a matter of a relatively simple script.  JUnit will require some work, too.  At least it all seems to be doable with reasonable resources.  Unfortunately, technical debt always has its cost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Binary Compatibility chapter of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html) is explicit about the fact that reordering of elements in the class files is permitted:

> [...] here is a list of some important binary compatible changes that the Java programming language supports:
>
> - [...]
> - Reordering the fields, methods, or constructors in an existing type declaration.
> - [...]
> - Reordering the list of direct superinterfaces of a class or interface.

That means that the order in which they appear in the .class file is not dictated by the specifications. If you want to rely on it, you have to either (1) know for a fact that your specific implementation uses the same order as the definition order (testing it, like you've done, is a good idea but does not guarantee anything), or (2) change the order yourself.

Comment: "Binary Compatibility" does *not* necessarily mean that the result is exactly the same. It only means that code compiled against the older version will continue to work (or at least load/link) with the newer version.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I accept that, but in my eyes it can be inferred from that that different compilers are permitted to generate class files with different method order for the same class... which I think translates to "not dictated by the spec".

Comment: I agree with the "not dictated" part, I just don't think this chapter is a good argument for that.

Answer (score 3):

Class.getDeclaredMethods API is clear about this "...The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order...". Most likely the reason of that is that javac is not obliged to generate methods in .class in any particular order.